# Athena shows no value against boolean column, table created using glue crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am using aws glue csv crawler to crawl s3 directory containing csv files. Crawler works fine in the sense that it creates the schema with correct data types for each column, however, when I query data from athena, it doesn't show value under boolean type column.

A csv looks like this:

```
"val","ts","cond"
"1.2841974","15/05/2017 15:31:59","True"
"0.556974","15/05/2017 15:40:59","True"
"1.654111","15/05/2017 15:41:59","True"
```

And the table created by crawler is:

```
Column name Data type
val         string
ts          string
cond        boolean
```

However, when I run say `select * from <table_name> limit 10` it returns:

```
    val         ts                      cond
1   "1.2841974" "15/05/2017 15:31:59"   
2   "0.556974"  "15/05/2017 15:40:59"   
3   "1.654111"  "15/05/2017 15:41:59"
```

Does any one has any idea what might be the reason?

I forgot to add, if I change the data type of `cond` column to `string`, it does show data as string e.g. `"True"` or `"False"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Glue classifies the `cond` column as boolean, because Athena will not understand that value as a boolean. I think this is a bug in Glue, or an artefact of it not targeting Athena exclusively. Athena expects boolean values to be either `true` or `false`. I don't remember if that includes different capitalizations of the strings or not, but either way yours will fail because they are quoted. The actual bug is that Glue has not configured your table so that it strips the quotes from the strings, and therefore Athena sees a boolean column containing `"True"` with quotes and all, and that is not a supported boolean value. Instead you get `NULL` values.

You could try changing your tables to use the [OpenCSVSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html) instead, it supports quoted values.

It's surprising that Glue continues to stumble on basic things like this. Glue is unfortunately rarely worth the effort over writing some basic scripts yourself.